# How can I reuse a function for many different ID values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a jQuery snippet I wrote to achieve show/hide effect on a page. The `s1,s2,s3...` are IDs of button divs. There will be about 25 of them.
When a button s1 is clicked, a div q1 will hide and a div q2 will show.

Is there a succinct way of writing just one such snippet to cover all the cases
at once instead of 26?

```
$("#s1").click(function(e) {
         $("#q1").hide();
         $("#q2").show();
         });

$("#s2").click(function(e) {
          $("#q2").hide();
         $("#q3").show();
         });

 $("#s3").click(function(e) {
         $("#q3").hide();
         $("#q4").show();
         });
.
.
,
.
.
.
.
.
$("#s25").click(function(e) {
         $("#q25").hide();
         $("#q26").show();
         });
```

Comment: Include HTML code please

Comment: This is not a good way to handle your task. Reliance on IDs should be a last resort. Instead, put a shared class on your elements and use _DOM traversal_ to select elements to toggle.

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML? It sounds like you could have a button click event, pull the number from the ID of the clicked button, hide the `q` with that number, and show the `q` with that number incremented by one. Better yet, you could skip IDs altogether and just use some matching based on the elements' relationships in the DOM.

Comment: Depends on the HTML. Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Yes. Hint: use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and some DOM traversal — where are the `q` elements in relation to their corresponding `s` elements in the DOM? You could just calculate the right IDs. You can use [multiple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#Selector_lists) at once. You can also use CSS classes instead.

Comment: That are way too many IDs. This sounds like you are doing something wrong/way more complicated than necessary. How you could do that better depends on your markup. I'd bet you can get rid of all the IDs and just add a single class to all the DIVs. Not only making this easier to read, but also more flexible and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop?

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 25; ++i) {
  $("#s" + i).click(function(e) {
     $("#q" + i).hide();
     $("#q" + (i + 1)).show();
  });
}
```

Also, small tangential tip: you don't need to declare the parameter "e" if you're not going to use it :)

Comment: I’d recommend event delegation instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to handle your task. Reliance on IDs should be a last resort. Instead, put a shared class on your elements and use DOM traversal to select elements to toggle.

```
<a class="my-trigger-element-class">...</a>
<div class="my-toggled-element-class">...</div>

<script>
$('.my-trigger-element-class').click(function() {
    // here I assume that the toggled element immediately follows the trigger
    // this may not be the case, so adjust accordingly
    let toggledEl = $(this).next('.my-toggled-element-class');

    // hide all elements that aren't the adjacent one
    $('.my-toggled-element').not(toggledEl).hide();

    // show just the adjacent one
    $(this).next('.my-toggled-element-class').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Examine virtually any jQuery accordion script to see this in action. They all use a variation of it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use a `data-xxx` attribute on the button to make a general hide/show button.
An example could be like this

HTML:

```
<button class="show-hide-button" data-show="#q2" data-hide="#q1">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
$(".show-hide-button").click( function(e) {
    $($(this).data('show')).show();
    $($(this).data('hide')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give each of your buttons a class, and add a click event listener to elements with that class. When the button is clicked, you can get its id number using `this.id.match(/\d+/g);`, and use then use the number retrieved in your other selectors:

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  const [n] = this.id.match(/\d+/g); // get number from the id
  $("#q"+n).hide();
  $("#q"+(+n+1)).show();
}
```